# Условия на php

Tags: php

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать условия на php? Если можно, то пример.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле в PHP существует далеко не один единственный оператор условия. Один из таких - тернарный оператор:

```
$speed = 55;
echo ($speed < 60) ? "Скорость в пределах нормы" : "Превышение скорости !";
```

Ну и три основных оператора логического условия:

```
if
else
elseif
```

О них можно почитать [здесь](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?co)